# Displaying KML file in Google Earth for Android

Tags: kml, google-earth, android

I have created some 3D buildings and route in KML format and it worked properly in Google Earth (desktop). When I put it in Google Cloud Drive and open it by Google Earth for Android, none of the model can be seen.

Does Google Earth for Android support this KML file or are there any changes in coding is required?

Are there any resources available from Google to test the KML file in Google Earth for Android?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways :

1. You can use extra app, just to convert your KML files to "earth" file (the file become ready to use in google earth android) in [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.wrightrocket.kmlkmz&hl=en)
2. Maybe now you use Earth 8.0, please uninstall it and use another version of Google Earth for your Android. Check [Google Earth 7.1.2.2011](http://google-earth.en.uptodown.com/android/download/49309)